# How to to queue telegram bot calls using Celery in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, celery, python-asyncio, python-telegram-bot

I'm running a Flask app for scheduling shifts. Every time the schedule is adjusted, I want to update the picture of the schedule in pinned message of my telegram group chat. For this I use a telegram bot. The bot is called through the `python-telegram-bot` library, and is only active for this particular call. I'm not polling or getting updates from the bot at any other time.

Everything works great - except that the Telegram API is a little slow. Currently the call to the bot is done using `asyncio`. My Flask app waits until the bot responds, causing the UI to freeze. I am trying to offload this task to a Celery worker.

I can't figure out what the right approach for this is. The telegram library uses the `await` statement, but this is not compatible with Celery. Any help is appreciated!

This is the asyncio call:

```py
asyncio.run(schedulebot.update_schedule())
```

And this is the method:

```py
class ScheduleBot:
    ...
    async def update_schedule(self):
        bot = Bot(token=self.bot_token)
        chat = await bot.get_chat(chat_id=self.group_chat_id)
        message = chat.pinned_message
        with open(image_path, "rb") as image:
            new_photo = InputMediaPhoto(media=image)
            await bot.edit_message_media(
                chat_id=self.group_chat_id,
                message_id=message.message_id,
                media=new_photo,
            )
```